# Design Patterns for Android -- Ensure GPS Location is set

Tags: android, android-gui

I'm writing an Android App that uses my GPS Location. My code is very simple.

```
public class MyActivityThing extends Activity {

Location                    l;
MyLocationListener          locationListener;
LocationManager             locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.car, menu);
    return true;
}

public void setHotColdLocation(View view)
{
    l = locationListener.getCurrentLocation();
}
}
```

Here is my MyLocationListener

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

private static Location thelocation;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    thelocation = location;
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

public Location getCurrentLocation()
{
    return thelocation;
}
}
```

My situation is this. I have a button that `onClick` calls the `setHotColdLocation` method in `MyActivityThing`.

My question is, how should I ensure that the location is set when the user presses the button? The `onLocationChanged` method is not called immediately, so when the app first starts I can press the button and cause an exception....

Should I make the button invisible until the location is called? 
Should I just enclose the contents of `setHotColdLocation` in a try catch and throw away the users clicks until the location is set?
I can think of tons of ways to make it work, but I don't know the best one...or the right one.

Any help?

Comment: Why not just put in a null check? =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to put it is that your button can **start a task** that ultimately sets the location.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I'm new to Android. I guess I'll use an AsyncTask.